# Return last URL in sequence of redirects

Tags: python, python-requests

I sometimes need to parse with Beautiful Soup and Requests URLs that are provided as such:

> http://bit.ly/sdflksdfwefwe
>
> http://stup.id/sdfslkjsfsd
>
> http://0.r.msn.com/sdflksdflsdj

Of course, these URLs generally 'resolve' to a canonical URL some as `http://real-website.com/page.html`. How can I get the last URL in the resolution / redirect chain?

My code generally looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, from_encoding=response.encoding)
canonical_url = response.??? ## This is what I need to know
```

Note that I don't mean to query `http://bit.ly/bllsht` to see where it goes, but rather when I am using Beautiful Soup to already parse the page that it returns, to *also* get the canonical URL that was the last in the redirect chain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the `url` attribute of your `response` object.

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://bit.ly/bllsht')
>>> response.url
  > u'http://www.thenews.org/sports/well-hey-there-murray-state-1-21-11-1.2436937'
```

*You could easily find this information in the [“Quick Start” page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)*.

Comment: So unbelievably simple! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the link. It appeared to me that the `url` property would be the URL that was specified in the `get()` method.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing for urllib2?

Comment: @Pythoner1234 please, ask a separate question next time (or, even better, search first, as there is already a similar question). Basically, the answer is: you'll have to do this manually.